# Return number of rows deleted from only one command within a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is returning some other number, and I can't quite figure it. Here's the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCandidate(@candidate_id int) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NumCandidatesDeleted AS int;
    SET @NumCandidatesDeleted = 0;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION ucDelCand

        /* I've removed some code from here for brevity */

        DELETE FROM [answers] WHERE [candidate_id] = @candidate_id;
        DELETE FROM [documents] WHERE [candidate_id] = @candidate_id;

        DELETE FROM [candidates] WHERE [candidate_id] = @candidate_id;

        SET @NumCandidatesDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION ucDelCand

    SELECT @NumCandidatesDeleted;
END
```

And here's my C# (winforms) calling code:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteCandidate", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@candidate_id", CandidateId);

var rows = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // This seems to return a variety of int values
```

I have also tried `RETURN (@NumCandidatesDeleted)` in the SP. What am I missing?!!

**Edit:**
I only want to return the number of candidates deleted. i.e. the affected rows from the final `delete`.

**Solution** (problem?):
The *answer* is: the code I posted should work as intended.
The *problem* was the "code I removed for brevity" (sorry). I still won't post it all, for, well ... brevity. BUT, the offending line was an additional `SELECT` statement earlier on. Therefore when the `ExecuteScalar` was called it was giving me the first `SELECT` rather than the last one.

To the next wonderer in a similar predicament - be sure to try your stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio. And if you remove code to make it more concise...do state that's what you've done (sorry. again.).

---

Thanks to all who answered and responded. Big help. Hope the next monkey stuck with Stored Procedure Return values finds this and is helped too!

Comment: ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row of the result set. Did you maybe intend to use ExecuteNonQuery to get the number of affected rows?

Comment: Use `ExecuteNonQuery` if you're not returning rows and you can refactore your stored procedure to have the `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: You should make NumCandidatesDeleted an OUTPUT parameter. Also, you should be explicit about your parameter datatypes and values instead of using AddWithValue.

Comment: @Lennart, if I use ExecuteNonQuery which "affected rows" count will be returned? Can I control that? - will it be from the last operation in the SP?

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the value and see if the value matches?

`DELETE FROM [candidates] WHERE [candidate_id] = @candidate_id;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;`

Comment: The code you posted looks like it should work.  What kind of numbers or values is it returning?

Comment: @noelicus I assume it's the number of rows affected by the transaction, that's how I understand the docs. I'm not a DB-expert though, just struck me as odd because I used ExecuteNonQuery in a similar manner.

Comment: It's been returning small numbers. 1-6. There should be 1 candidate and a few documents and a few "answers". The numbers are too small to be the sum of affected rows. It could be the documents I suppose. But that would be so random!

Comment: Thanks everyone, especially @RBarryYoung: I wanted to know above all whether what I had pasted above *should* be working. As ever, I removed some of the beginning of the SP code that I felt would have made the question verbose (my own types, calls to another SP via a cursor etc). That code included another `SELECT` statement and so the final `SELECT` or `RETURN` was actually the second batch of stuff returned and missed by the Scalar request. 
ANYWAY. 
Big thanks - all your comments and answers have seriously helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could try refactor the stored procedure to include an OUTPUT parameter:
Since `@@ROWCOUNT` returns the number of rows affected by the last statement, you need to populate your variable with the `@@ROWCOUNT` value and then increment it after each delete statement to capture the correct number of rows deleted. You can read more about [`@@ROWCOUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) on MSDN:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCandidate 
      @candidate_id INT, 
      @total_deletions INT OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NumCandidatesDeleted AS int;
    SET @NumCandidatesDeleted = 0;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION ucDelCand

        DELETE FROM [answers] WHERE [candidate_id] = @candidate_id;
        SELECT @NumCandidatesDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;

        DELETE FROM [documents] WHERE [candidate_id] = @candidate_id;
        SELECT @NumCandidatesDeleted = @NumCandidatesDeleted + @@ROWCOUNT;

        DELETE FROM [candidates] WHERE [candidate_id] = @candidate_id;
        SELECT @NumCandidatesDeleted = @NumCandidatesDeleted + @@ROWCOUNT;    

    COMMIT TRANSACTION ucDelCand

    SELECT @NumCandidatesDeleted;
END
```

C#

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteCandidate", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@candidate_id", CandidateId);
SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter("@total_deletions", SqlDbType.Int);
output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(output);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var rows = output.Value;
```

Comment: Using an OUTPUT feels like a workaround. I use stored procedures for returning to a scalar in other places. V confused!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Declare @tempTable as table
(
pkid bigint null,
tablename nvarchar(200)
)

Delete Tablename
OUTPUT Deleted.pkid,'Tablename'
INTO @tempTable 
From Tablename
```

code in above prosedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteCandidate(@candidate_id int) AS
BEGIN
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION ucDelCand

DECLARE @tempTable as TABLE 
( 
    pkid bigint null, 
    tablename nvarchar(200) 
)

DELETE [answers]
OUTPUT DELETED.candidate_id, 'answers'
INTO @tempTable 
FROM [answers] WHERE [candidate_id] = @candidate_id;

DELETE [documents]
OUTPUT DELETED.candidate_id, 'documents'
INTO @tempTable
FROM [documents] WHERE [candidate_id] = @candidate_id;

DELETE [candidates]
OUTPUT DELETED.candidate_id, 'candidates'
INTO @tempTable
FROM [candidates] WHERE [candidate_id] = @candidate_id;

SELECT COUNT(pkid), tablename
FROM @tempTable
GROUP BY tablename

COMMIT TRANSACTION ucDelCand
END
```

Comment: Hi @Sourav_Agasti,  i think, i have given correct answer, there are no need to edit my answer

Comment: Hi @Sourav_Agasti,  i think, i have given correct answer, there are no need to edit my answer

Comment: I improved the formatting, did not change the original answer dude.

Comment: ok not an issue, i think, this way which i am answered, is better way what you think??